# A sequence defined by $a_1=2,a_2=\frac{4}{5}$ and $a_{n+2}=a_n^2-2a_{n+1}-4(n\ge 1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, recurrence-relations, recursion

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence satisfying $a_1=2,a_2=\frac{4}{5}$ and $a_{n+2}=a_n^2-2a_{n+1}-4(n\ge 1)$. Prove that

1. $|a_n|\le 4$;
2. $\prod_{k=1}^n |a_{2k}|\le \frac{5}{\sqrt{11}}$.

By graphing recursively, one can suspect $$2|a_n-4|<a_{n+1}<\frac{1}{4}a^2_{n},$$ but which is still hard to prove.

Comment: @user376343 I don't see a problem with the sequence, first few terms are about $2.0, 0.8, -1.6, -0.16, -1.12, -1.7344, 0.7232, -2.4382566, 1.39953152, -0.8539676, -0.3333763, -2.60398668, 1.31911314, 0.14252036, -2.5449812, 1.1102745, 0.2563804, -3.280051, 2.6258337, 1.50706965, -0.11913684, -1.49046738, -1.00487166, 0.231236319, -3.4527056, ...$

Comment: The negative terms however clearly show the OP's suspicion is wrong, $a_{n+1}$ can easily be negative.

Comment: mengdie1982, apparently I did a mistake, sorry :)

Comment: If you reopen the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4726921/find-the-minimum-tau) you just closed, I have an answer to it :)

Comment: @TheSilverDoe THX. But someone has posted a solution here：https://www.zhihu.com/question/609084366/answer/3094687640

Comment: @mengdie1982 Ok. My answer is quite different, though, so don't hesitate.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood. Thanks!